# is this the correct way to redirect multiple domain aliases with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have 4 domain redirects like this in `.htaccess` but it doesn't appear to be working. Am I doing this correctly?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydoma.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^medomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^moodomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^madomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: How are these domains defined in `VirtualHost`?

Comment: I think I narrowed down the problem. It redirects fine if I call the domain only like `http://www.mydoma.in` but if I call `http://www.mydoma.in/something` it doesn't redirect.

Comment: If you rename this .htaccess does it still redirect?

Answer (score 0):

There are different way of doing this. Depending what you exactly need. See [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx). Of course you have to make sure Source and Destination are correct in the first place.

Comment: I think I narrowed down the problem. It redirects fine if I call the domain only like `http://www.mydoma.in` but if I call `http://www.mydoma.in/something` it doesn't redirect.